# Como retornar 2 vetores de diferentes tipos em C++

Tags: c++, funções, return, vector

Realizo um cálculo e meu resultado está salvo em um

> `vector<int>`

e um

> `vector<string>`

Como faço para fazer minha função retornar esses dois parâmetros no meu `main()`?

```
int  cracking(string chemform) {

    vector<int> pos;
    vector<int> multi;  // Vector of multipliers
    vector<string> parte; // Vector of atoms
    int conta, i, conta2, local, chk;
    string temp, temp2;
...
return 0;
}
```

Queria retornar multi e parte. Vi algumas pessoas falando de *template* mas me parece que só funciona quando quero escolher um tipo, queria usar os dois. É possível tal coisa?

Uma opção seria transformar o vetor de inteiros em um vetor de *string*, porém não também não sei se é possível passar mais de um vetor de uma função.

Comment: Qual a relação entre `multi` e `parte`? Não seria de repente o caso de ser um `vector<par_multi_atom> multipart`, contendo uma estrutura composta pelos multiplicadores e pelos átomos?

Comment: Poderia, o problema é que eu preciso que essa função seja responsável por essa tarefa, não posso jogar mais um processamento no main.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem muitos meios para fazer a função retornar vetores, o mais simples acredito eu, retornar uma estrutura contendo esses 2 vetores .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct retVec{
    vector<int> multi;  // Vector of multipliers
    vector<string> parte; // Vector of atoms
};

retVec cracking(string chemform) {

    vector<int> pos;
    vector<int> multi;  // Vector of multipliers
    vector<string> parte; // Vector of atoms
    int conta, i, conta2, local, chk;
    string temp, temp2;
    retVec retv = {multi,parte};
    return retv;
}
int main()
{
    //cout<<"Hello World";

    retVec vec=cracking("");
    vector<int> multi = vec.multi;
    vector<string> parte = vec.parte; 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que estou vendo aqui, seu problema é representação de conhecimento, mais especificamente sobre a composição de moléculas e íons.

## Semântica reversa

O meu primeiro ponto de atenção foi o nome da função, `cracking`. Do [Wikcionário](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/crack#Verbo):

> **crack**
>
> 1. craquear
> 2. craquelar
> 3. estalar
> 4. falir
> 5. rachar

Normalmente, em computação e programação, vejo muito mais o uso do sentido 1, [**craquear**](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/craquear):

> inutilizar um sistema de bloqueio ao uso irrestrito ou de acesso restrito de um programa de computador com a utilização de um craque informático

Ou seja, relacionado a segurança. Quebrar criptografias, chaves de acesso a um sistema off-line, coisas assim.

Então me deparo com o argumento dessa função: `chemform`. No começo não me indicou nada de nada, então desci um pouco mais. E descendo cheguei nos comentários.

Nominalmente, o que me chamou a atenção nos comentários foi que eles estavam em inglês. Ora, se eles estão em inglês, então é possível que *outras partes* também estivessem... `chemform`? `chem-form`? *chemestry formula*!

Ok, então o argumento é uma fórmula química. Então o que seria o *cracking* disso? Não parece que se está tentando fazer um ataque cibernético e forçar o álcali a revelar seus segredos terrosos... então ***crack** 6. rachar*?

Se deseja então rachar a fórmula química de um composto? Interessante... então, o que se deseja saber com essas partes? Um conjunto indexado de multiplicadores e um conjunto indexado de átomos? Preciso retornar ambos. Mas e a terceira variável indexada? `pos`? Isso permanece um mistério.

## Como quebrar uma fórmula química?

Bem, isso depende de muitos fatores.

De modo geral, fórmulas químicas não são representações lineares, mas sim são árvores que foram simplificadas para facilitar a impressão e comunicação através de sequências de caracteres.

Um exemplo de representação mais adequado a árvore é um sal de mercúrio (I): nitrato de mercúrio (I).

Esse sal consiste de dois ânions nitrato NO<sub>3</sub><sup>1-</sup> e um cátion de mercúrio (I) Hg<sub>2</sub><sup>2+</sup>. Sua representação é Hg<sub>2</sub>(NO<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>.

Por que isso acontece? Bem, acontece que mercúrio tem dois estados iônicos possíveis:

1. Hg<sup>2+</sup>
2. Hg<sub>2</sub><sup>2+</sup>

Portanto, a segunda forma, com dois mercúrios e após perder 2 elétrons, tem em média carga 1+. Mas não acontece de o mercúrio aparecer sozinho com apenas um elétron perdido. Outros pontos interessantes de elementos que aparentam poder se simplificados de acordo com a proporção de átomos relativos à fórmula química da molécula/do íon:

1. Diátomos homonucleares
2. Outras formas alotrópicas
   De modo geral, tentando fazer uma simplificação da fórmula molecular, O<sub>2</sub> e O<sub>3</sub> poderiam ser simplificados para O, mas isso não reflete as propriedades químicas dessas 2 substâncias
3. Ácido fluorídrico
   As pontes de hidrogênio formadas entre o flúor e o hidrogênio são tão fortes quanto ligações covalentes entre o hidrogênio e o flúor, portanto é representado como (HF)<sub>2</sub>, não como HF

Também tem o caso, mais especial para íons, em que o íon tem uma carga de oxidação como um todo, mas não para suas partes separadas:

1. Peróxido O<sub>2</sub><sup>2-</sup>, com número de oxidação médio de -1
2. Superóxido O<sub>2</sub><sup>1-</sup>, com número de oxidação médio de -1/2

## Forma de representação

A forma de representação de uma substância, de maneira intuitiva, é dado pelas seguintes regras:

- Uma fórmula química consiste de uma ou mais partes
- Uma parte consiste de um quantizável, seguido de um índice (subescrito) de quantidade e de um índice (sobrescrito) de carga (índice passível de omissão)
- São quantizáveis:

  - Átomos
  - Fórmulas químicas
- Quando um quantizável consiste de uma fórmula química de mais de uma parte e ele tem um índice, normalmente se coloca parênteses antes dos índices

Por exemplo, derivando nitrato de mercúrio (I) em cima dessas regras:

1. Fórmula química
2. Parte Parte
3. Quantizável índice Quantizável índice
4. Hg<sub>2</sub> (Fórmula química)<sub>2</sub>
5. Hg<sub>2</sub> (Parte Parte)
6. Hg<sub>2</sub> (N O<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>

Mais formalmente, isso é uma gramática livre de contexto. A demonstração de que é livre de contexto cabe uma resposta a parte, mas ela apresenta auto-aninhamento, o que já a exclui de ser regular, sendo de um nível mais poderoso; também tem o fato de que uma "parte" não interfere em outra, portanto cada "parte" pode ser interpretada sem necessitar de contexto externo, portanto "livre de contexto".

A gramática para tal seria, começando de `F`:

```
F ==> P
F ==> MP
MP ==> MP P
MP ==> P
P ==> Qs
P ==> Qs I
P ==> Qc
P ==> (Qc) I
Qc ==> F
Qs ==> <<átomo>>
I ==> <<número>>
```

Onde:

- `F`
  fórmula
- `MP` e `P`
  multi-parte e parte
- `Qs` e `Qc`
  quantizável simples (um átomo) e quantizável completo
- `I`
  índice indicativo de quantidade
- `<<número>>`
  um número
- `<<átomo>>`
  um dos aproximadamente 120 elementos conhecidos pela química, representado aqui pela sigla atômica

No caso da fórmula pro nitrato de mercúrio (I), a derivação mais à esquerda é (terminais indicados entre aspas):

```
F
MP
MP P
P P
Qs I P
"Hg" I P
"Hg" "2" P
"Hg" "2" "(" Qc ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" F ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" MP ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" MP P ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" P P ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" Qs P ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" "N" P ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" "N" P ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" "N" Qs I ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" "N" "O" I ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" "N" "O" "3" ")" I
"Hg" "2" "(" "N" "O" "3" ")" "2"
```

Essa é a árvore de derivação que representa a fórmula passada. Esse é exatamente o conhecimento indicado por Hg<sub>2</sub> (N O<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>, nem mais nem menos.

Agora, o que é o `cracking`? É obter o conhecimento do jeito que ele foi passado de maneira manipulável útil para o computador trabalhar? Pelo que indica (retorno de um conjunto indexável de átomos e um conjunto indexado de multiplicadores), creio que não. Creio que seja mais próximo representar a proporção de cada átomo na molécula/íon argumento.

Aparentemente, o desejado era representar seus átomos e seus respectivos multiplicadores. A sua solução é a solução marcada como aceita consiste em ligar essas duas informações simplesmente pelo posicionamento. Então `vec.multi[i]` e `vec.parte[i]` é o jeito correto de obter o átomo e seu multiplicador. Isso significa que é plausível obter quantidades diferentes para o mesmo átomo, basta que ele esteja em índices distintos. Como por exemplo o álcool etílico CH<sub>3</sub>CH<sub>2</sub>OH, em que o hidrogênio aparece em 3 lugares distintos.

Eu não sou a favor dessa representação, pois é sempre necessário fazer dois acessos de vetor para obter uma informação. Eu sou mais a favor da representação indicada pelo Maniero: identificador do átomo e multiplicador juntos. Assim, para saber quem é seu átomo e seu multiplicador, basta fazer um acesso de vetor. Basta fazer `atoms[i]`. Por mais que se faça `atoms[i].multiplie` e `atoms[i].part` para pegar o multiplicador e a parte, teria uma maior chance de aproveitar o *cache* do processador devido à localidade. Talvez compiladores espertos possam identificar que `atoms[i]` seja uma operação idempotente (no sentido que `Atom a = atoms[i]; Atom b = atoms[i];` fará com que `a` e `b` tenham os mesmos valores) e só realizar ela uma única vez.

Uma outra maneira de representar seria através de um `hashmap` ou coisa do gênero, onde o átomo seria a chave do mapa e ele armazenaria quantidades. A vantagem desse método é que é garantido que ele só armazene cada átomo uma única vez. Mas no momento que é um `hashmap`, você abdica do fato de ser um conjunto indexável e passa a conviver com um conjunto não indexável. Se o índice te importava antes, bem, você o perdeu. Precisaria de mais estruturas auxiliares para representar o átomo, o multiplicador e o índice em um `hashmap`.

Ainda na ideia do `hashmap`, você pode criar um `hashmap` de tamanho fixo que não sofrerá com possíveis aumentos na tabela de espalhamento. Como? Bem, temos menos de 120 átomos distintos conhecidos. Esse número está cada vez mais difícil de subir, talvez 200 átomos esteja além do limite que os cientistas sejam capazes de fabricar. Então podemos mapear cada elemento ao seu respectivo número atômico. Por exemplo, hidrogênio ocuparia a posição 1, hélio a posição 2, carbono a posição 6, nitrogênio a 7 e assim por diante. Existiria um vetor estático no código relacionando números atômicos à átomos, talvez uma árvore de busca representando o contrário.

Answer (score 1):

Tem algumas formas, mas a mais comum seria criar o vetor  na função chamadora e passar para a função chamada como argumento. Na verdade o ideal seria passar uma referência para o vetor, ou alocar o vetor no *heap*.

Uma outra possibilidade é ter uma outra estrutura que encapsule os dois vetores, ou ainda ter só um vetor com uma estrutura que encapsule os dois membros necessários, o que parece ser o caso.

É possível retornar ambos com ajuda de uma outra estrutura, mas a performance seria horrível. Mesmo se tivesse que retornar apenas um vetor único desta forma a performance seria ruim por ter que copiar o vetor de uma função para a outra.

O conceito está errado e parece ter indícios de outros problemas no código ou na percepção do problema.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Atom {
    int multiplier;
    string part;
};

vector<Atom> cracking(string chemform) {
    return { { 10, chemform }, { 20, "teste" } };
}
int main() {
    vector<Atom> atoms =cracking("item");
    cout << atoms[0].multiplier << " " << atoms[0].part << endl;
    cout << atoms[1].multiplier << " " << atoms[1].part << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KBKlGn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/juniafcy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/ReturnStruct.cpp).

Comment: que frunção seria possível utilizar para essa segunda opção sugerida? Tenho duvida na metodologia

Comment: @PatrickMachado coloquei do jeito que acho mais correto, coisas correlatas devem ficar juntas, então me parece que optando por dois vetores o conceito permanece errado, e conceitos errados podem funcionar de cara, mas geram problemas futuros.

Comment: Quem negativou pode dizer o que tem de errado? Ou se já foi consertado, favor mudar o voto.

Comment: 3 negativos? Quase um ataque

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado por que quase? :)

Comment: @Maniero para _me dar_ margem de erro e poder me defender caso alguém diga que estou julgando ruim as pessoas =P

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado um foi revertido porque a pessoa exagerou nos negativos em mim :)